# When I try update an element in a line my file, the wrong element get updated in C. How access each element in a line in a file?

Tags: c

I am creating a task management system where the user can add,modify and delete their tasks. But I am facing errors with modifying elements in a line in a file.
This is where I add tasks to the file:

```
void add_task()
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char category[50];
    char info[50];
    char date[20];
    char status[20];

    char another = 'Y';
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("Tasks.txt","r+");

    if (fptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nSYSTEM ERROR");
        fptr = fopen("Tasks.txt","w");
        getchar();

        return;
    }
    while (another == 'Y'|| another == 'y')
    {
        fseek(fptr,0,SEEK_END); 
        printf("\nTo Add a new task enter the details below\n");
        printf("Enter an ID to identify your tasks easily(LESS THAN 5 CHAR):");
        scanf("%d",&id);
        printf("Name of Task:");
        getchar();
        fgets(name,50,stdin);
        name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Category of Task:");
        fgets(category,50,stdin);
        category[strcspn (category, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Information about task(Max 49 characters):");
        fgets(info, 50, stdin);
        info[strcspn (info, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Due Date of Task(yyyy/mm/dd):");
        scanf(" %s", date);
        printf("Status of Task\n TD = To-Do\n IP = In Progress\n CT = Completed Task\nEnter Status:");
        scanf(" %s", status);
        fprintf(fptr,"%d %s %s %s %s %s\n",id, name, category, info, date, status);

        printf("\nDo you want to add another record (Y/N)");
        fflush(stdin);
        another = getchar();
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    printf("\n\n\tPress any key to exit");

    exit(0);

}
```

This is where I want to change only the category of the task but it changes the name instead:

```
void change_category()
{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    char category[50];
    char info[50];
    char date[20];
    char status[20];
    int i;
    FILE * fptr = fopen("Tasks.txt","r");
    FILE * fp = fopen("temp.txt","w");
    printf("Enter the ID of the task you want to update:");
    scanf("%d",&id);
    while(fscanf(fptr,"%d",&i) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(fptr,"%s",category);
        fgets(info,50,fptr);
        if(i == id)
        {
            printf("Task Found");
            printf("\nUpdating category for task with ID: %d",id);
            printf("\nEnter new category:");
            scanf("%s",category);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"%d %s %s\n",i,category,info);

    } 
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fptr);
    remove("Tasks.txt");
    rename("temp.txt","Tasks.txt");
}
```

Sample entry into the file:

```
8291 Math Math HW Pg 1-2 2022/04/03 IP
```

Update Category entry:

```
English
```

Updated File:

```
8291 English Math HW Pg 1-2 2022/04/03 IP
```

Comment: In `add_task` the fields written are `id, name, category, info, date, status`.  In `change_category` the fields written are `id, category, <rest of the original line>` writing `category` where the original name field was. You're also probably writing over the beginning of the next line too since "English" is longer than "Math".

Comment: `fprintf(fp,"%d %s %s\n",i,category,info);` says put the new category value as the second field. You need to fscanf the name and output it and the categroy to the new line

Comment: How could I do it for the information because it contains spaces